# Implementing MATLAB's filter function in Swift or Python

Tags: python, swift, matlab, signal-processing

I am trying to the equivalent of MATLAB's `filter` function in Swift code. MATLAB's filter function is defined as follows:

```matlab
filter(b,a,x)
```

> y = filter(b,a,x) filters the input data x using a rational transfer function defined by the numerator and denominator coefficients b and a.
>
> - If a(1) is not equal to 1, then filter normalizes the filter coefficients by a(1). Therefore, a(1) must be nonzero.
> - If x is a vector, then filter returns the filtered data as a vector of the same size as x.
> - If x is a matrix, then filter acts along the first dimension and returns the filtered data for each column.
> - If x is a multidimensional array, then filter acts along the first array dimension whose size does not equal 1.

I realize that Python has the numpy module and associated functions to help implement this function. However, I am not aware of a similar toolset within the context of Swift.  I really would like to avoid the logic of implementing a rational-transfer function, so I was wondering if there was an existing Swift module or reference for this. I could also translate a bare-bones implementation written in Python into Swift.

Does `filter` exist in Swift?

Comment: I would doubt that Swift has any digital signal processing modules built in. I would also guess that it isn't fast enough to perform filtering in a satisfactory way. The implementation of filter in Matlab and Python is Direct Form II. There many explanations for how this works if you want to try it yourself. I suspect that the best solution would be to write it in C and then wrap it somehow (which is what Matlab and Numpy have done).

Comment: Have you looked at scipy.signal?

Answer (score 1):

In python you have a similar function [scipy.signal.lfilter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html).